# Post 500 (Internal Server Error) line 48 app.js and error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 line 65 in app.js

Tags: javascript

I am attempting my first weather app and I believe my POST and GET routes haave something wrong with them but I am not sure what.  I got a 500 error which is the most general error so I am having trouble debugging.

github: https://github.com/mylaconcepts/Weather-Journal-App

```js
//Client side code
const getData = async (url = '', data = {}) =>{

    const req = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            date: data.date,
            temp: data.temp,
            content: data.content
          })
    });
    try {
        const newData = await req.json();
        console.log(newData);
        return newData
    }catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
};

//server side code

app.get('/all', (req, res) => {
  res.send(projectData);
})

app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
 
  const newData = {
      temp: req.body.temp,
      date: req.body.date,
      feelings: req.body.feelings
  };

  projectData.push(newData);
  //res.send(newData);
  console.log(newData);

})
```

Error message:

[image: error message]

Answer (score 2):

You see that error because you are trying to JSON parse what is looking like an HTML response. Also based on the status 500 it looks like you have an unhandled exception somewhere in your server.

Seeing your [source code](https://github.com/mylaconcepts/Weather-Journal-App/blob/56aa800de53cbe27c75c1a0d5d0f39ff4c823b7e/server.js#L2), you are initializing `projectData` as an object, and then [trying to do](https://github.com/mylaconcepts/Weather-Journal-App/blob/56aa800de53cbe27c75c1a0d5d0f39ff4c823b7e/server.js#L40) `.push()` to it, which is most likely the cause of the server error.

```js
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = {};

//...

app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
 
  const newData = {
      temp: req.body.temp,
      date: req.body.date,
      feelings: req.body.feelings
  };

  // This will throw an exception like "projectData.push is not a function":
  projectData.push(newData);
  //...
})
```

To fix it, a solution can be declaring the `projectData` properly as an array:

```js
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = [];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I had the object at the top of the server side code in the complete code.  You can see if you look on Github.  I removed the push but am still getting the same errors

Comment: I've checked your repo latest commit `server.js` file, and it looks broken. Check your `app.post('/add', (req, res) => {` handler, it's missing closing brackets and a `res.send()`-like call to send the response.

Comment: fixed!  Thank you